# Важно ли указывать дженерики при инициализации

Tags: java

Есть код

```
List<List<String>> refActualTo = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> refCoef = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> fileGroup = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<List<String>> fileGroupName1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Переменные, объявленные с использованием дженериков и нет, работают одинаково.
Почему в некоторых книгах рекомендуют прописывать при инициализации дженерики, ведь это усложняет читабельность кода?

Answer (score 13):

Это называется `diamond types`. Если быть кратким, то эту фичу ( чтобы не писать второй раз List) ввели в java 1.7. Соответственно, видимо авторы книги пишут либо на java 1.6, либо просто сохранилась такая привычка.